# Set monolog formatter in config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

Is there a possibility to simply just add `formatter: json` on config.yml of Symfony, in order to define what formatter to use on every Monolog instance?

Comment: [http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/formatter.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/formatter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## app/config/config.yml

services:

```
json:
    class: Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter
```

monolog:

```
handlers:
    file:
        type: stream
        level: debug
        formatter: json
```

Comment: Or, if using symfony/monolog-bundle, reference directly "monolog.formatter.json".